# Relay turning off circuit

Tags: relay

[image]

I have a circuit that must turn off a relay (like uploaded picture.)

When I use a BD139 transistor in this circuit, it works and the relay remains off.  When I use a BCX56-16 transistor the relay doesn't turn off.

Can anyone tell me that how this circuit works and how can I calculate transistor's base and collector resistors? Why doesn't the relay turn off when I use a BCX56-16 transistor?

The Zener is 4.9V.  When the relay is ON, the red point has 36V.  When relay is off the  red point has 12V. I tried different base resistors (1k 4.7k 15k 47k) but the relay did not turn off.

Comment: Why don't you use a 230V relay and get rid of all your circuit ? There are many issues on this circuit.

Comment: I have seen many diagrams, but this I don't understand.